# Deploying both testing and production versions of an SPFx Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

I am trying to figure out how to deploy two versions of an SPFx Webpart to the App Catalogue. We need one for production and one for development.

What I have tried so far:

- Modifying the ID in the *.manifest.json file
- Modifying the ID in the package-solution.json file
- Changing the name (as well as the filename) of the solution

Each time I deploy the production version, SharePoint comes up with the following error:

> SharePoint SPFx Component ID {0} exists in solution {1} already.

Edit: Following some advice in [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216869/run-development-and-production-versions-of-the-sp-fx-web-parts-in-two-different?rq=1), it still makes no difference.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue was the fact I never really bothered generating new IDs from scratch. I simply copied the existing ones and replaced the last character in the GUID strings.

Example:

```
6b021be2-9a6c-5f16-2fd6-735ba545d2cb  // Existing GUID
6b021be2-9a6c-5f16-2fd6-735ba545d2cc  // New GUID
```

Does anyone know if SharePoint does partial matches of these strings when comparing?

Answer (score 1):

With the release of [a site collection app catalog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog), you now also have the option of multiple site-collection scoped SPFx web parts.

"Previously, all add-ins and SharePoint Framework solutions had to be managed centrally in the tenant app catalog. While tenant administrators could delegate the access to other people in the organization, a deployed package was visible on all site collections. SharePoint offered no supported way of deploying add-ins and SharePoint Framework solutions only to specific sites.

With the introduction of site collection app catalogs, tenant administrators can enable app catalog on the specific sites. Once enabled, site collection administrators can deploy SharePoint add-ins and SharePoint Framework solutions that will be available only in that particular site collection."

The only limitation appears to be [a lack of Application Lifecycle Management API support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog#application-lifecycle-management-alm-apis-are-not-yet-supported).

Answer (score 1):

- Added New GUID in WebPart.manifest.json
- Added New GUID in package-solution.json
- Renamed Name in package-solution.json

Then the issue got resolved